# Preloading images for CSS animations?

Tags: image, animation, css, preload

I have a css animation on an image and I want it to play when the page loads. What is currently happening is that the image get loaded without the animation playing the first couple of times you load the page. After that is works fine. I'm guessing the image gets cached.

Is there a way to pre load the image so that the animation works straight away?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than preload the image, I'd recommend not applying the animation until the image has loaded. Using jQuery, you can apply a class to the image only once everything has loaded:

```
$(window).bind("load", function(){
    $("#future-head-hand").addClass("loaded");
});
```

Then apply the animation to that class instead:

```
.loaded {
    position: absolute;
    left: 60%;
    bottom: -40%;
    margin-left: -190px;
    -webkit-animation-name: FadeIn;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-animation-name: movinghand;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish the same thing by moving all your `js` to the bottom of your `html` so that it loads after all of the css and images.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Adobe Edge, you can go into `View > Preloader Stage` and add a spinner, or something like that, to show that the animation's loading, before it's actually ready.